# Right widget completely visible in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to have two widgets next each other whereas the right widget is always completely visible. In this case, the two icons are not completely visible.

[image]

This is my source code approach but it isn't working with `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis`.
My intention of the widgets would be that the texts on the left side are ending with

> **...**

if their are to long. **How can I make the widget 2 always completely visible?**

```
new Row(children: <Widget>[
        // ### Widget 1 ###
        new Column(children: <Widget>[
            new Text("A very long strings sassaasasasasasasssss", overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
            new Text("Another very long string skaskajsakaskjsa", overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
        ]),

          // ### Widget 2 ###
          /* should be visible in full size on the right in every situation */
          new Expanded(child:
            new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    child: new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green, size: 35.0), onPressed: () async {
                    }),
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                  ),
                  new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.remove, color: Colors.red, size: 35.0), onPressed: () async {
                  }),
                ],
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min
            )
          ),
        ]
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is your `Text` widgets are inside `Column` widget, which is resize according to it's childs(in this case `Text` widgets). So, `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` will not do anything here, until you wrap your text widgets in `Column` widget.

One way to fix this is to wrap `Column` widget using a [`Flexible`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) widget and use [`flex`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html) property as you want.

Fixed code should look like below:

```
new Row(children: <Widget>[
  // ### Widget 1 ###
  new Flexible(  // newly added
    flex: 2,  // newly added
    child: new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // newly added
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,  // newly added
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text("A very long strings sassaasasasasasasssss",
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
        new Text("Another very long string skaskajsakaskjsa",
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
      ],
    ),
  ),

  // ### Widget 2 ###
  /* should be visible in full size on the right in every situation */
  new Expanded(
    child: new Row(
    //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // coomented because will not do anything here
    children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
        child: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.check,
                color: Colors.green, size: 35.0),
            onPressed: () async {}),
        margin: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
      ),
      new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.remove, color: Colors.red, size: 35.0),
          onPressed: () async {}),
    ],
  )),
]),
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a more complex version than the first answer. But your version gives also more freedom for UI design.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ListTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) with its implemented `trailing` which simply adds a widget at the end of the row:

```
ListTile(
    title: Widget1,
    trailing: new Row(
        children: <Widget> [
            IconButton, 
            IconButton
        ]
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you. What I like about this version that it is simple and really good! However there is a little bit of padding in front of the title widget.